# Find the area of the intersection of a general disk and unit square

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, geometry, area

> What is the area of the unit square $U = [0,1]\times [0,1]$ intersected with a disk centred at $x=(a,b)$ with radius $r$: $B(x,r) = \{y\in\mathbb R^2\mid\|y-x\|\leqslant r\}$, a ball

Here was my original approach:

$$ \int_0^1\int_0^1 \int_B dxdydr = \int_0^1\int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^p p  ~dxdydpd\theta = \frac{2\pi}{3}$$

Clearly it is wrong as it should depend on $r$. I've not considered the boundaries on where they do not intersect, for that, I need to integrate this region but I'm not sure how? How can I parametrise the path of $(U \cap B)'$?

Comment: What's the point $x$?

Comment: wait, if $B(x,r)=\{y\in\mathbb R^2:\|y-x\|\leqslant r\}$, then $x,y$ must be elements of $\mathbb R^2$ (so $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^4$). Is the area supposed to be a function of $x$? that is, $x$ being a generic point?

Comment: Is $r$ a generic radius too?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: Then your approach is wrong, since the result is a constant, where the area you want to find depends on $x,r$ (for example, for certain values of $x,r$ the disc and the unit square don't intersect, so the area should be $=0$)

Comment: OK, how may i approach this then? I know that the area is at most $B$ which has area $\pi r^2$

Comment: Not only does the answer not depend on $r$, nothing you wrote depends on $r$, starting from the very first step. You should be integrating over $U\cap B(x,r)$, not just $B$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes i didn't consider cases on the boundary, so now this seems a lot more complex.. perhaps I need to compute a set of equations for the path of $B$ outside of $U$ and then subtract this from the area of $B$ i.e. $\pi r^2$?

Comment: Yes as $x$ changes, the area of intersection will change.

Comment: @MathLover So i wonder maybe i should set $r$ to be fixed for a few cases, then how could i approach it now? i.e. when $r=\{0.25, 0.5, 1\}$

Comment: The question is tedious with radius as $r$ instead of a numerical value. Depending on $r$ and $x$, which lines of the square are intersected will change and that will change how you set up the  integral.

Comment: @MathLover exactly, so i mean instead of a general $r$, how would I approach the two cases when $r=0.5$ or $r=1$?

Comment: Take $r=1$ and you have $5$ cases: circle intersects only one of the boundary lines of the square in two points, intersects two adjacent lines, intersects two parallel lines, intersects $3$ lines of the square in $4$ points and lastly the square is completely inside the circle.

Comment: Can one assume that you are able to identify the boundary of the intersection in question (i.e. the intersection points and the lines connecting these points).

Comment: @user Yes i think so

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can identify the boundary $\Gamma$ of the intersection in question (i.e. the intersection points and the lines connecting these points) the area can be computed using the Green's theorem as
$$
\frac12\oint_\Gamma (xdy-ydx).
$$
The integral is trivial along the sides of the square and along the parts of the circle you can use the parametrization: $x=a+r\cos\phi,y=b+r\sin\phi$, so that the resulting integral is also explicitly integrable.